# IsCustomerPortal field to be covered in test class

Tags: apex, code-coverage, customer-community, customer-portal

```sql
SELECT Id,IsCustomerPortal, Retailer_Stage__c, CreatedDate,Registration_Date__c 
FROM Account 
WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Distributor' AND BillingCountry = 'India' 
    AND **IsCustomerPortal** = TRUE;
```

Unable to cover **IsCustomerPortal** field in test class -- [field is not writable: Account.IsCustomerPortal]

Tried to create Community User and Portal user with below code with dummy data

```java
private static User createPortalAccountOwner() {  
     UserRole portalRole = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE DeveloperName = 'Test_Group' LIMIT 1];     
     insert portalRole;  
     System.debug('portalRole is ' + portalRole);  
     Profile sysAdminProfile = [Select Id from Profile where name = 'System Administrator'];  
     User portalAccountOwner = new User(  
         UserRoleId = portalRole.Id,  
         ProfileId = sysAdminProfile.Id,  
         Username = 'portalOwner' + System.currentTimeMillis() + '@test.com',  
         Alias = 'Alias',  
         Email='portal.owner@test.com',  
         EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',  
         Firstname='Portal',  
         Lastname='Owner',  
         LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',  
         LocaleSidKey='en_US',  
         TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles'     
     );  
     Database.insert(portalAccountOwner);  
     return portalAccountOwner;  
   }
   
    private static void createCommunityUser(User portalAccountOwner) {  
     System.runAs ( portalAccountOwner ) {  
       //Create account  
       Account portalAccount = new Account(  
           Name = 'portalAccount',  
           OwnerId = portalAccountOwner.Id  
       );  
       Database.insert(portalAccount);  
       //Create contact  
       Contact portalContact = new Contact(  
           FirstName = 'portalContactFirst',  
           Lastname = 'portalContactLast',  
           AccountId = portalAccount.Id,  
           Email = 'portalContact' + System.currentTimeMillis() + '@test.com'  
       );  
       Database.insert(portalContact);  
       User communityUser = new User(  
           ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Interconnection Community User Plus User'].Id,  
           FirstName = 'CommunityUserFirst',  
           LastName = 'CommunityUserLast',  
           Email = 'community.user@test.com',  
           Username = 'community.user.' + System.currentTimeMillis() + '@test.com',  
           Title = 'Title',  
           Alias = 'Alias',  
           TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',  
           EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',  
           LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',  
           LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',  
           ContactId = portalContact.id  
       );  
       Database.insert(communityUser);  
     }  
   }
    User portalAccountOwner = createPortalAccountOwner();  
    createCommunityUser(portalAccountOwner);
```

Comment: Which line of your code is the error coming from?

Comment: Are you sure the assigned UserRole (`portalRole`) is setting the Owner as a true Portal role user? `IsCustomerPortal` is set only when the Account has an Owner with the appropriate Role and a Contact related to a Partner or Customer license through User relationship.

Comment: It seems you forget to add Account's `BillingAddress` and `RecordType` while creating Account record in your test class, where Account's `BillingCountry ='India'` and `RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Distributor'`

Comment: Hi @DavidCheng  could you please help me to provide sample code to cover IsCustomPortal = TRUE? I am confused with Portal Role user and owner..

Comment: Hi @TSmith could you please help me to provide sample code to cover IsCustomPortal = TRUE? I am confused with Portal Role user and owner..